# Oracle: Use of notational parameters which calling functions in insert statements not allowed?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-00907

Why does Oracle 10 R2 not allow use of notational parameters while calling functions in insert statements ?

In my app, I'm calling a function in an insert statement. If use notational method of parameter passing, I get an `ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis` error message

```
INSERT INTO foo
            (a,
             b,
             c)
VALUES      (c,
             F1(P1=>'1', P2=>'2', P3 => '3'),
             e)
```

Changing the same to position based parameter passing, and the same code gets compiled with no errors.

```
INSERT INTO foo
            (a,
             b,
             c)
VALUES      (c,
             F1('1','2','3'),
             e)
```

Why is this so ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it was a feature [added in 11g](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO06944).

Comment: Before then the `=>` was only allowed when calling PL/SQL programs from other PL/SQL programs.